# RN Navigation - Draw Navigator

Tags: android, react, react-native, navigation-drawer

Meu app vai possuir vários tipos de navegação em diferentes telas. 
Comecei utilizando a index com stacknavigator e numa segunda página to tentando configurar a DrawNavigator e não estou conseguindo.

Vi em um post de exemplo como se tivesse que inciar e registrar o app com o draw primeiro. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Seria interessante você indicar qual post viu isso tambem.

Comment: Nesse: https://developerlife.com/2017/04/15/navigation-and-styling-with-react-native/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer utilizando com Stack e drawer. No meu caso o drawer é a primeira screen da Stack e funciona. O código está assim:

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  HomeDrawer: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  SettingsDrawer:{
    screen: SettingsScreen
  }
});
const App = StackNavigator({
  Drawer: {
    screen: Drawer,
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  },
  View: { screen: ViewScreen },
})

export default App;
```

Neste caso Home e Settings são acessiveis a partir do drawer e view só é acessivel a partir da stack.